# Rails: How to have no response until an event triggers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asynchronous, triggers, response, event-driven

I don't know if Rails has a way to do as following:

1. Receive a request
2. Put the request into the monitor list until an event triggers
3. Finish the request but does not return any response to the client (no HTTP response), the trigger will do the response later after processing.

I found some info about delayed_job, but it returns the response immediately and puts the job to the background which does not seem to be event-driven.

Anyone can help?

Andy.

Comment: Do you know anything else, that has a way to do this? If you are talking about long running jobs, submitted over http, its generally done by enqueing the job in a queue and returning a job id, which client can query to get the current status of the job. If job has been completed, return a url to the resource, where client can get additional details.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about callbacks. Read here: [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html). Note that you can create custom events and callbacks too: [blog](http://mutuallyhuman.com/blog/2009/01/06/using-custom-activerecord-events-callbacks)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for [Notifications](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Notifications.html), [Observers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html), and/or [COMET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)