# sending data back in response after SOAP call

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

So I would like to to this:

1. receive a POST from external url in controller and capture data
2. use this data in SOAP request; use response back from SOAP request to modify data and then
3. send data back to external client in the response to external url in step 1.

It seems I have some timing issues in my approach as the object returned to external client is empty. If I comment out my Savon code doing the SOAP call the object is complete. Here is the short version of what I am doing using Rails 3.0.9, Savon 0.9.7

1) works great

```
#
# get object from POST
#
string = request.body.read
@myobject = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(string)
```

2) also works great (leaving out most of Savon magic as response has precisely what it should)

```
...
response = client.request :urn, "MySOAPOperation" do
...
```

3) Here is where I am a little "off"

```
response_hash =response.to_hash[:my_soap_operation_response]
@myobject.status = response_hash[:status].to_s
logger.info ("Status:    " + @myobject.status)
#
# at this point myobject updated values are confirmed in log
#
respond_to do |format|
   format.json { render :json => @myobject }
end
```

Now the response is correctly forwarded back to Step 1. external client but with @myobject empty. If I comment out the SOAP request and response the full @myobject is sent along with response to the client. I am thinking this is a timing issue as I also obtained the same result by commenting out the SOAP request and adding

```
sleep 20
```

in its place. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thank you for reading.

Dan

Comment: you are saying that @myobject is not nil and that you actually have something in there when you ask rails to render it?

Comment: No. The object is empty - most likely NULL - when the target request (a php application) receives it. Before it gets shipped off in response, the object is complete in the rails log.thx.

Comment: I need to ask more questions: The requester is a php application? It sends a request to your rails-app which responds properly and the php application sees nothing?

Comment: Yes. If I comment out the SOAP call the php application receives a complete object. With the SOAP call the php application receives a NULL object. This SO post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972393/rails-how-to-have-no-response-until-an-event-triggers) led me to try ActiveSupport::Callbacks. More info on that here: (http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=46779).

Answer (score 0):

The culprit turned out to be settings on the PHP side of things.

Before (empty object returned):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
```

After (complete object returned):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
```

Comment: As soon as you are able to, be sure and mark this answer as accepted so others will know that there is a solution.